# Guaranteed convergence zero-finding method for systems of equations?

Tags: algorithms, roots, nonlinear-system, recursive-algorithms

I am looking into methods of approximating zeros of functions, in particular for systems of nonlinear equations.

I have discovered that Newton's Method can easily be applied to an m-by-m system of equations, but convergence seems to be difficult to prove...

For m=1 systems, the bisection method is guaranteed to converge, but I haven't found any sources outlining how to achieve guaranteed convergence for systems of equations.

Are there any methods with guaranteed convergence for systems of equations? If not, can anybody recommend sources outlining how to analyse whether or not Newton's method will converge?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Even in the 1D case, there is no method to guarantee convergence *to all solutions* for general functions. All you can have is a method that will find *some* root in an interval where you detected a change of sign by some magic. The situation is different when you know some properties of the functions, such as a bound on the derivative.

Comment: So, assuming that we are looking for a specific root (or a specific root-vector for a system of equations), and we know approximately where to begin, are there any methods which guarantee convergence?

Comment: You can do multidimensional bisection, you only have to replace the sign change condition by the condition that the mapping degree is not zero . The mapping degree can be calculated as an integral over the boundary, so requires some effort.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I'm talking about! Can you recommend a source for me to learn this properly?